# Is there a designer for Xamarin xaml files?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, xamarin, designer

I am currently starting an Xamarin Application. Now i wonder if there is any form of designer for the UI, so I do not have to start the application over and over again to test the UI while designing?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer

Comment: Currently we have two tools for better `XAML`(Xamarin Forms) development and those are [Gorilla Player](https://grialkit.com/gorilla-download/) and [LiveXAML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionoy.XamarinFormsLive-18843).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no designer.

The closest thing will be the [Xamarin Live Player](https://www.xamarin.com/live) which is currently in Preview.

Another alternative is the [Xaml Previewer for Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/)

Comment: thanks for the fast answer! i will test it right now and tell you if it works!

Comment: well, xaml previewer is not working and xamarin live player only works with visual studio 15.3 preview. how do i update to this version? it only showed me version 15.2

Comment: In order to install 15.3 preview you need the preview installer which you can get here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes
There are details instructions how to use the Live Player here:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/install/

Do you get an error message for the Xaml Previewer? This happens sometimes when your Xaml Page doesn't have a parameterless constructor or if your JDK or Android SDK is out of date and needs updates

Comment: thanks, i will try that later!
the error says "There was an internal issue with the rendering process."

Comment: xaml previewer for xamarin.forms is working, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are two tools used as said by cheddy - Gorilla Player and Live XAML. I have tried the gorilla player but it doesnot work for dot Net standards. then I found Live XAML which is a great live development toolalong with the XAML previewer. So I personally prefer to use Live XAML.

Answer (score 1):

All those xamarin live player, live previewer, inspector, gorilla player are useless the more your app grows. maybe for basic, small apps and if you dont use any DI or 3rd party tools like from telerik or syncfusion and you have to do a lot of set ups, face with connection lost problems etc etc. Only fully working extension is [LiveXaml](http://www.livexaml.com/) extension which is unfortunately not free.