# Editing position of elements in XamarinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I dont khow how to enable the feature that can edit the position of elements like button and image in xamarin forms . but i have this feature in wpf (Im using Visual Studio 2022)

i tried to find out a way to fix it and really i didnt find any way to fix it.

*** I dont mean Xaml Live Preview ***

Comment: there is no visual designer for Xamarin

Comment: Duplicate question. [Is there a designer for Xamarin xaml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306659/is-there-a-designer-for-xamarin-xaml-files). [No, there isn't. That older Q&A shows the closest alternatives.]

Answer (score 0):

> I dont khow how to enable the feature that can edit the position of elements like button and image in xamarin forms . but i have this feature in wpf (Im using Visual Studio 2022)

As Jason and ToolmakerSteve said that "there is no visual designer for Xamarin."

For similar thing you can refer to this case: [Is there a designer for Xamarin xaml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306659/is-there-a-designer-for-xamarin-xaml-files).